# Passive element in GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I have in a Swing dialog a `JLabel` that offers a multi-line description, so its contents are wrapped in `<html><body width="...">` tags. The dialog also contains a `JComboBox` which should be the source for the layout manager to determine the dialog's width -- if there is a long option, it should be wider.

Unfortunately, the label always has the same width due to the absolute pixel value, and if I set it to `100%`, it blows up the dialog to the screen's width while trying to display its contents in a single line.

Is there an option in `GridBagLayout` to let it ignore a component's width while calculating the overall width and then just give it a value?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `JLabel` to wrap the text maybe you can use a `JTextArea` and use the `setLineWrap(...)` method to control wrapping. Then you can use the `setColumns(...)` method to control the width of the text area.

You can change the background color of the text area to make it look like a JLabel.

> Is there an option in GridBagLayout to let it ignore a component's width while calculating the overall width and then just give it a value?

No, but you might override the `getPreferredSize(...)` method of the `JLabel` to do your own custom calculation. You might be able to fix the width based on a custom property you set on your custom label. Not sure how the height would be determined. I've never looked at the logic for HTML wrapping size calculation.

Answer (score 0):

While @camickr wrote his answer, I've implemented a workaround: I now set the text of the `JLabel` as the last step before calling `pack()` on the dialog and do it like this:

```
String labelText = "<html><body>";
labelText += "<p style=\"width: " + (comboBox.getPreferredSize().width) + ";\">";
labelText += "This is text.";
labelText += "</p></body></html>";
```

So I basically ask the combo box for its preferred size and use that as the HTML style `width` attribute.